# Combining more than 1 test into one.

Tags: calculus

Let's say I have a series, and I was asked to determine whether it converges or not, and I have decided to use comparison test and end up with an equality by any means, my question is do I always have to compare it to either a p-series or gseries like tutors suggest? or can I apply test for divergence and thats it?

Comment: I don't understand the situation. How do you come up with an equality when you are using the comparison test?

Comment: either increasing the denominator or reducing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant theorems are:

Suppose $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ converges and for all $n$, $0 \leq b_n \leq a_n$. Then $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty b_n$ converges.

Suppose $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ diverges to $\infty$, and for all $n$, $0 \leq a_n \leq b_n$. Then $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty b_n$ also diverges to $\infty$.

The primary insight here is that we must begin with a series we already know to be convergent (or divergent). Your professors probably advised you to begin with a $p$-series or a geometric series because it's easy to tell whether a $p$-series or geometric series converges or diverges. But in theory, this test can be used with $a_n$ being any sort of series at all, as long as it's a nonnegative series and we know in advance whether it converges or diverges.